# Is there a classification for the generating sets of symmetric group?

Tags: group-theory

Is there a classification for the generating sets of symmetric group? Or, is there an algorithm for checking wheather a subset is a generating set?

For example, can $S_7$ be generated by all its $4$-cycles? Can $S_7$ be generated by all its $4$-cycles whose entries are consecutive i.e. $\{(1 2 3 4), (2 3 4 5),\dots,(7 1 2 3)\}$?

Comment: No,yes,yes,yes.

Comment: @DerekHolt Any detail please?

Comment: For the algorithm, there is Schreier-Sims which can calculate the order of any subgroup of $S_n$ with given generating set. There is also a very fast Monte-Carlo algorithm, which first tests for transitivity, and then chooses random elements, looking for a $p$-cycle with $n/2 < p < n-2$. If it finds one, then $G=A_n$ or $S_n$. If it fails to find one after several tries then it is highly improbable that the group is $A_n$ or $S_n$.

Answer (score 4):

The subgroup generated by all four cycles is normal and contains odd elements, so it is $S_7$.